# Regex not working as wanted removing custom tag names

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to run this regex but fail. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
$return = "<list>{eated}</list><full><b>Eated:</b> {eated}<br>"
         ."<b>Liked Me:</b> {likeme}<br><b>Seen:</b> {seen}<br>{image}</full>";

echo preg_replace("%<list.*?</list>%i", "", $return);
```

Comment: There should be `/` instead of `%` in `preg_replace`.

Comment: @Wiktor completely incorrect. The regex delimiter can be any character

Comment: @Wiktor: not true, you can specify any delimiter!

Comment: @Alexxus: ymmv. at least the whole line shows without scrolling

Comment: @collapsar For now you may be right, but SO could change the design in the future. Would you then reformat all the stuff to fit again?

Comment: @Alexxus: the same argument holds for every change of the SO formatter. in fact, the original presentation might become harder to read upon a SO design change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error.

```
echo preg_replace('/(<list>.+?)+(<\/list>)/is', '', $return);
```

that replaces what the tag and its contents just fine.

Comment: Btw, wasn't your original regex working? It [seemed to work fine](http://ideone.com/IwVsVq). In your current regex, you can easily remove all the capture groups.